# Vim Tab switching weird behaviour

Tags: vim

I'm very new to vim and might be asking a very dumb question, but I've added a keyboard shortcut to switch between tabs, but when I do switch this happens[image]

Instead of the tab indicator moving it moves everything, I don't know how to explain this with words but I think you get my point with the gif. Is there any way of changing this to a normal tab switching like browsers do?

The shortcuts I'm using are:

:`noremap <C-n> :bnext<CR>`

:`noremap <C-n> :bprevious<CR>`

Comment: FYI: `gt` and `gT` are Vim default tab switching mappings. See `:h gt`

Comment: @PeterRincker just checked the help you suggested and there was a tabnext command that fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it by changing from `bnext` and `bprevious` to `tabn` and `tabp`....